# Unix Timestamp + 5 минут

Tags: php, дата, unix

Здравствуйте!

ест вот такое число 1522141200 это unix дата (2018-03-27 12:00:00)

как мне к числу 1522141200 добавить 5 минут?

то есть если я распечатаю `echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", '1522141200');`  я получил бы сегодня 2018-03-27 12:05:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unix-Timestamp - это количество, секунд, прошедшее с полночи 1 января 1970 года.

Соответственно, если вам нужно сдвинуть ваше значение на какой-то интервал, переведите этот интервал в секунды и прибавьте или вычтите полученное значение.

Итого ответ

```
$old = 1522141200;
$new = $start + 5 * 60;  // 5 минут * 60 секунд
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Переведите 5 минут в секунды и прибавьте:

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1522141200);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1522141200 + 5 * 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

В данном вопросе очень наглядно можно воспользоваться функцией [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php). Например:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 min', 1522141200));
// получим 2018-03-27 13:05:00

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+3 week', 1522141200));
// получим 2018-04-17 13:00:00
```

Недостаток - явно выполнение этой функции займет больше времени чем арифметические вычисления.

Преимущество - текстовое именование интервала нагляднее чем магические числа в коде